# Can a Turing Machine be defined over many languages?

Tags: turing-machines

What does it mean, if possible, for a Turing machine to be defined over many languages?

Comment: The mistake is that the Turing Machine defines the language. It only defines one language, which is the set of all inputs it halts and accepts on. If there are two languages for which a TM halts and accepts on, then they must be the same language or they are subsets of the language defined by the TM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Turing machine isn't defined over a language.

Given a Turing machine $M$, we can define the language of inputs on which $M$ halts; or the language of inputs which $M$ accepts; or the language of inputs which $M$ either accepts or doesn't halt on; and so on.

Usually we are interested in either the language of all inputs on which $M$ halts, or (for a machine halting on all inputs), in the language of all inputs which $M$ accepts.

Comment: what is the difference between the language realised by a problem and the language of inputs on which M halts?

Comment: I don't know what is the language "realised" by a problem; this is not a standard term. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "problem" here.

Comment: I define the language realised by a problem as the set containing all of the solutions to that problem. Saying that out loud, I believe this would be the same as the set that the TM halts+accepts on. I have seen these two definitions, I guess they mean the same thing

Comment: A problem or language is not the same thing as a Turing machine. You're confusing the two.

Comment: The language realised by a decision problem A is the set of all strings that are the solutions for that decision problem. The language realised by a TM is the set of all inputs that the TM halts+accepts. In this sense, I believe the two languages would be the same, if the TM was solving the decision problem A